# What is the value of `this` in the code shown not the global object?

Tags: javascript, oop, this, executioncontext

**Running this code on VSCode:**

Observe the code below :

```
value = 10;
console.log(global.value); // 10
console.log(this.value);   // undefined
```

Why does `this.value` evaluate to `undefined` and not `10`? Doesn't the `this` keyword always point to the global object outside of a function?

Comment: Are you running this in a nodejs envrionment? If so, `this` refers to `module.exports` at the top level.

Comment: because global is undefined. Remove `global.` from the first `console.log` your code will work fine.

Comment: @maddy23285 This looks like nodejs code. In nodejs [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#global) exists. OP would be getting a different error if `global` didn't exist.

Comment: If it helps in understanding how that's possible, nodejs [wraps your code](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#the-module-wrapper) in a module wrapper (for CJS modules), so that code above is actually in a function, just one you can't see.

Comment: @Nick Parsons I'm running this code using VSCode. Sorry if this info isn't helpful but I'm a total newbie to programming :)

Comment: @noSelf_ That hints that it's nodejs, but when you run it in vs code, how do you do that? Are you running `node <filename>.js` to run it (or doing something like `npm start`/`nodemon` maybe?)

Comment: @maddy23285 As far as I know, I'm running this code in VSCode `without` strict mode.

Comment: @Nick Parsons No I'm running it using VSCode shortcut for linux (alt + ctrl + n).

Comment: @noSelf_ when you do that, does it show `[Running] node ...`? Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU8eB.png)?

Comment: @Nick Parsons yes

Comment: Nice, that means node is being used to execute your script. The above comments and links should cover what’s going on in your script

Comment: @Nick Parsons cool. I understood what you said about node modules. It makes sense now. Thanks!